# how to show all elements of vectors and matrices in Julia

Tags: julia

When I have many elements in an array, Julia REPL only shows some part of it. For example:

```
julia> x = rand(100,2);

julia> x
100×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.277023   0.0826133
 0.186201   0.76946  
 0.534247   0.777725 
 0.942698   0.0239694
 0.498693   0.0285596
 ⋮                   
 0.383858   0.959607 
 0.987775   0.20382  
 0.319679   0.69348  
 0.491127   0.976363
```

Is there any way to show all elements in the vertical form as above? `print(x)` or `showall(x)` put it in an ugly form without line changes.

Comment: Don't know a concrete way to do that but following might be enough ? `for i=1:size(x,1)
           println(x[i,:])
       end
`

Comment: I think we need to add something like this. It would be worth filing a request on Discourse or on GitHub.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*NOTE: in 0.7, `Base.STDOUT` has been renamed to `Base.stdout`.  The rest should work unchanged.
---*

There are a lot of internally used methods in [`base/arrayshow.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/f3118ce6a39b1adeac345c6ddd9c46d9f6676316/base/arrayshow.jl) doing stuff related to this.  I found

```
Base.print_matrix(STDOUT, x)
```

to work.  The limiting behaviour can be restored by using an `IOContext`:

```
Base.print_matrix(IOContext(STDOUT, :limit => true), x)
```

However, this method only prints the values, not the header information containing the type.  But we can retrieve that header using `summary` (which I found out looking at [this](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/92879ea7802804a0c16f70c081c56773ce3946a9/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/src/bidiag.jl#L219)).

Combining both:

```
function myshowall(io, x, limit = false) 
  println(io, summary(x), ":")
  Base.print_matrix(IOContext(io, :limit => limit), x)
end
```

Example:

```
julia> myshowall(STDOUT, x[1:30, :], true)
30×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.21730681784436     0.5737060668051441 
 0.6266216317547848   0.47625168078991886
 0.9726153326748859   0.8015583406422266 
 0.2025063774372835   0.8980835847636988 
 0.5915731785584124   0.14211295083173403
 0.8697483851126573   0.10711267862191032
 0.2806684748462547   0.1663862576894135 
 0.87125664767098     0.1927759597335088 
 0.8106696671235174   0.8771542319415393 
 0.14276026457365587  0.23869679483621642
 0.987513511756988    0.38605250840302996
 ⋮                                       
 0.9587892008777128   0.9823155299532416 
 0.893979917305394    0.40184945077330836
 0.6248799650411605   0.5002213828574473 
 0.13922016844193186  0.2697416140839628 
 0.9614124092388507   0.2506075363030087 
 0.8403420376444073   0.6834231190218074 
 0.9141176587557365   0.4300133583400858 
 0.3728064777779758   0.17772360447862634
 0.47579213503909745  0.46906998919124576
 0.2576800028360562   0.9045669936804894 
julia> myshowall(STDOUT, x[1:30, :], false)
30×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.21730681784436     0.5737060668051441 
 0.6266216317547848   0.47625168078991886
 0.9726153326748859   0.8015583406422266 
 0.2025063774372835   0.8980835847636988 
 0.5915731785584124   0.14211295083173403
 0.8697483851126573   0.10711267862191032
 0.2806684748462547   0.1663862576894135 
 0.87125664767098     0.1927759597335088 
 0.8106696671235174   0.8771542319415393 
 0.14276026457365587  0.23869679483621642
 0.987513511756988    0.38605250840302996
 0.8230271471019499   0.37242899586931943
 0.9138200958138099   0.8068913133278408 
 0.8525161103718151   0.5975492199077801 
 0.20865490007184317  0.7176626477090138 
 0.708988887470049    0.8600690517032243 
 0.5858885634109547   0.9900228746877875 
 0.4207526577539027   0.4509115980616851 
 0.26721679563705836  0.38795692270409465
 0.5627701589178917   0.5191793105440308 
 0.9587892008777128   0.9823155299532416 
 0.893979917305394    0.40184945077330836
 0.6248799650411605   0.5002213828574473 
 0.13922016844193186  0.2697416140839628 
 0.9614124092388507   0.2506075363030087 
 0.8403420376444073   0.6834231190218074 
 0.9141176587557365   0.4300133583400858 
 0.3728064777779758   0.17772360447862634
 0.47579213503909745  0.46906998919124576
 0.2576800028360562   0.9045669936804894
```

**However**, I would wait for some opinions about whether `print_matrix` can be relied upon, given that it is not exported from Base...

Answer (score 9):

A short/clean solution is

```
show(stdout, "text/plain", rand(100,2))
```

Comment: Use code brackets (`\``) and try to say something more.