# A multidimensional array formatted with shell Array output in julia script/print()

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, printf, julia

When in the Julia shell if you run the function `zeros(5, 5)` you get something that looks like this:

```
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

If you store the multidimensional array in a variable and print it (or directly print it) in the shell or an external script, you will get the much uglier:

```
[0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
```

Is there a way to access the Array's builtin STDOUT formatter that displays it the human readable way in the shell?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49304329/1346276

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `display(x)` instead of `print(x)`.

Note that `print(x)` can be useful in situations where you need copy-paste-runnable code.

Answer (score 2):

to complete @crstnbr answer I would also suggest **show**

```
M=rand(2,3)
f = open("test.txt","w")
show(f, "text/plain", M)
close(f)
```

then if you read and print test.txt you get:

```
julia> print(read("test.txt",String))
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.73478   0.184505  0.0678265
 0.309209  0.204602  0.831286
```

note: instead of file f you can also use stdout.

To save some data in a stream the function **show** is more suited than **display**, as explained in the docs (**?display**):

> ```
>  In general, you cannot assume that display output goes to stdout (unlike print(x)
>   or show(x)). For example, display(x) may open up a separate window with an image.
>   display(x) means "show x in the best way you can for the current output device(s)."
>   If you want REPL-like text output that is guaranteed to go to stdout, use
>   show(stdout, "text/plain", x) instead.
> ```

Comment: Yes, makes sense to mention this as well!